Spring MVC Validation docs not clear
I am trying to understand the following section in the Spring MVC docs, (the Validation page):

Validation may be applied at one of two levels:



@ModelAttribute, @RequestBody, and @RequestPart argument resolvers validate a method argument individually if the method parameter is annotated with Jakarta @Valid or Spring’s @Validated, AND there is no Errors or BindingResult parameter immediately after, AND method validation is not needed (to be discussed next). The exception raised in this case is MethodArgumentNotValidException.




When @Constraint annotations such as @Min, @NotBlank and others are declared directly on method parameters, or on the method (for the return value), then method validation must be applied, and that supersedes validation at the method argument level because method validation covers both method parameter constraints and nested constraints via @Valid. The exception raised in this case is HandlerMethodValidationException.


Ok so from the first paragraph, I know that for example:
 @PostMapping("/person")
 public String createPerson(@Validated @ModelAttribute Person person) {
       
        // Handle the logic for creating the person
        // For example, save the person to a database (this part is omitted for simplicity)

    return "success";
}

This method will validate the received Person object using the @Constraints inside the Person class, for example:

public class Person {

    @NotNull
    @Size(max=64)
    @Size(min=2)
    private String name;

    @Min(0)
    private int age;
//...

and if validation fails, it will throw a MethodArgumentNotValidException.
Furthermore, this:
@PostMapping("/person")
    public String createPerson(@Validated @ModelAttribute Person person, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // handle error
            return "personForm";
   }

   // Handle the logic for creating the person
   
   return "success";
}

will not throw an exception, but will let me handle the error in the method.
What I don't understand is what they mean in the second paragraph - .. and that supersedes validation at the method argument level .. .
What is the meaning of this "superseding"? Considering the examples above - assuming that somehow method validation is applied on these methods - will or will not the Person object be validated? If so - in what way does method validation "supersedes" validation at the method argument level?
Let's run an experiment:
Consider a third version of the above method
@PostMapping("/person2")
public String createPerson(@RequestParam("id") @Min(20) @Max(40) int id, @Validated @ModelAttribute Person person) {
    System.out.println("GOT A PERSON");
    System.out.println(id);
    return "success";
}

The docs state that in this case, a method validation should apply - since we have a @Constraint annotation (@Min and @Max) on a method
parameter directly - so, in this case, there is a "superseding".
Running this example and sending a request with invalid values for User gives me the same result - a MethodArgumentNotValidException.

It will validate the method call and not the individual method argument as in the first case, hence also the difference in exception.

What happens if you put in invalid values for the id? You did use the proper annotations for your version of Spring (Boot)? And you did include not just the API but a proper implementation as well?
